# How to change default settings of linksys or other router?

Tags: router, wifi, defaults

The problem is that after power outage the router sometimes loses its configuration. Is there a way to store settings so they will survive any power outage? Or do you know any routers that by default have Wi-Fi disabled and don't allow connections to its administration panel (unless you e.g. physically push some button).

Comment: You may have better luck with this question if you say which model routers you are currently using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireless is disabled by default on any router that doesn't include wireless functionality ;-)

I think you could probably achieve this using open source firmware on the router.  Here's a couple of examples that will work on quite a few Linksys routers:

- [OpenWRT](https://openwrt.org/)
- [DDWRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index)

You should be able to edit the defaults in the config file in the source code, then recompile and apply to your router.

Comment: OK. I think I could recompile Tomato with different defaults. This should work. Would be better to have a ready and tested solution but I guess this will do.

Comment: It isn't *really* tested unless you tested it yourself in your own environment :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that you're using off the shelf consumer grade routers?

That's basically your problem - they're not designed for it. I don't know of any wireless router that would have wireless disabled by default- it sounds like you need a wired router..

Comment: No, I need wireless connections that are secure or off under any circumstances. It don't have to be shelf consumer grade, but I wouldn't mind if it has a low price ;-). Theoretically easy to do - there are many kinds of low cost NV memory. Practically - I just don't know. That's why I asked :-).